# How to return ArrayList from intent

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have code that passes an `arraylist` to another intent, how can I return the value of updated `arraylist` back to the main intent?

Arraylist in main intent code:

```
ArrayList<Users> vuser = new ArrayList<>();
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("vuser", vuser);
startActivity(intent);
```

Do I have to pass the `arraylist` again to the main intent? Like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("vuser", vuser);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Why not read this? https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result You need to execute "startActivityForResult()" and then retrieve modified ArrayList.

Comment: I was just about to answer your previous question if you want to undelete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass it using the `getIntent()` method. When you go back, you can override the `onBackPressed()` method and add your own login like the one given below. Check the code out:

```java
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
   getIntent().putParcelableArrayListExtra("vuser", vuser);
   finish();
}
```

This will send data to the previous activity and then finish the current activity.